# Pra que serve a classe Cache do Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Vi que o Javascript tem uma classe chamada [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache). Pelo pouco que consegui entender parece ter relação com requisições.

Eu queria saber um pouco mais sobre essa classe:

- Ela serve exclusivamente para apenas para requisições feitas com Request? Ou poderia ser usada com o XtmlHttpRequest padrão do Javascript?
- Essa classe pode ser usada para fazer cache de outra coisa, que não seja o que foi citado na primeira pergunta?
- Onde é armazenado esse cache?
- Qual é o suporte dessa funcionalidade? Se há falta de suporte, é possível fazer Polyfill?

Comment: Quem deu o negativo pode explicar o que pode ser melhorado?

Comment: visto que postou no StackOverflow em Português, acredito que ler a documentação em Português possa te ajudar, já deu uma olhada? https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Cache

Comment: @FellipeSanches acredito que pergunta seja sobre especificações técnicas a respeito da implementação da classe `Cache`. Tanto que o link que você passou está incluído na pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com a [especificação](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#cache):

> A Cache object represents a request response list. Multiple separate objects implementing the Cache interface across documents and workers can all be associated with the same request response list simultaneously.

Em Português livre:

> Um objeto Cache representa uma lista de resposta à requisição. Múltiplos objetos separados implementando a interface de Cache através de diversos documentos e workers poderão ser associados à mesma lista de resposta à requisição, simultaneamente.

**Respondendo suas perguntas:**

> Ela serve exclusivamente para apenas para requisições feitas com Request? Ou poderia ser usada com o XtmlHttpRequest padrão do Javascript?

Não, apenas com o Request. O cache foi desenhado para ser usado em princípio com Service Workers, e faz parte da especificação dele. A API do cache só armazena pares de objetos Request/Response, que representam respectivamente o request/response do protocolo HTTP. O `XMLHTTPRequest` é bem primitivo e em geral eu não recomendaria o uso dele para nada. O `fetch` tem bastante suporte hoje em dia, além de um bom [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch).

De certa forma, o cache pode ser visto como um `array` de objetos Request, funcionando como chaves das respostas, que o navegador em seguida armazena.

> Essa classe pode ser usada para fazer cache de outra coisa, que não seja o que foi citado na primeira pergunta?

Através do cache de requisiçōes você pode armazenar quase todo conteúdo estático de uma aplicação. O cache é praticamente todo o conteúdo de um ServiceWorker básico, e com ele você pode armazenar fontes, páginas (vide explicação logo a seguir), imagens, arquivos JavaScript, CSS, etc. Exemplo:

Importante notar que não necessariamente você precisa do Service Worker para utilizar a API, por exemplo para armazenar recursos estáticos, você não precisa:

```js
// Verifica que o navegador tem suporte para a API
if('caches' in window) {
  // Faz o cache de `assets` como fonte e imagem
  caches.open('meuCacheAqui').then(objetoDoCache => {
    objetoDoCache.addAll([
      '/assets/fonts/suaFonte.woff',
      '/assets/img/imagemBemBonita.jpg'
    ])
    .then(_ => console.log('Cache Realizado!'))
  })
}
```

Porém caso você queira armazenar uma página, então você precisaria de um Service Worker para manipular a requisição do navegador para recursos offline. Não daria para fazer com o Cache API sozinho.

O motivo de precisar de um ServiceWorker é que enquanto uma página pode ser lida e escrita através de um cache via `window.caches`, você precisaria de um ServiceWorker para interceptar a requisição inicial da página para então poder responder com um cache.

> Onde é armazenado esse cache?

No próprio navegador, dentro do perfil do usuário que acessou o cache, dentro da armazenagem do Service Worker. Nos navegadores baseados no Chromium, ele fica dentro da pasta `Service Worker`. Não sei dizer os outros.

> Qual é o suporte dessa funcionalidade? Se há falta de suporte, é possível fazer Polyfill?

Para o suporte, [veja o MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache#Browser_compatibility). Um Polyfill bem estável pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://github.com/dominiccooney/cache-polyfill).

Links úteis (Inglês):

- [Especificação do Cache API](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#cache)
- [O que pode ser armazenado no Cache API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/cache-api#what_can_be_stored)
- [Visão Geral do Cache](https://davidwalsh.name/cache)
- [Tempo de Vida de um Cache](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#cache-lifetimes)
- [Salvando uma resposta customizada utilizando o Cache API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619272/saving-a-custom-response-using-the-cache-storage-api)
- [Armazenando arquivos com o ServiceWorker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker)

Answer (score 7):

A API Cache, obviamente, serve para manipular o cache da aplicação, geralmente implementada com service worker para interceptar as requisições feitas pela aplicação

```
//Sempre que ocorrer uma requisição
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    //Se a origem da requisição for um xhr, fetch ou semelhante
    //o valor da propriedade destination será uma string vazia ('')
    console.log(event.request.destination || 'fetch');
    event.respondWith(
        caches.open('MyCacheName').then(function(cache) {
            return cache.match(event.request, {
                ignoreSearch: true
            });
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response ? 'from cahche' : 'from fetch')
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

No [FecthEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent) existe a propeiedade `request` do tipo [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) que por sua vez possui o atriuto `destination` do tipo [RequestDestination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RequestDestination), ela é uma string que contém o destino da resposta, ou seja, de onde foi feita a requisição, os possíveis valores são:

- "" The empty string is the default value of destination. What does it mean?
- "audio" The target is audio data.
- "audioworklet" The target is data being fetched for use by an audio worklet.
- "document" The target is a document (HTML or XML).
- "embed" The target is embedded content.
- "font" The target is a font.
- "image" The target is an image.
- "manifest" The target is a manifest.
- "object" The target is an object.
- "paintworklet" The target is a paint worklet.
- "report" The target is a report.
- "script" The target is a script.
- "serviceworker" The target is a service worker.
- "sharedworker" The target is a shared worker.
- "style" The target is a style
- "track" The target is an HTML .
- "video" The target is video data.
- "worker" The target is a worker.
- "xslt" The target is an XLST transform.

Para requisições feitas a partir da API `fetch` ou `XMLHttpRequest` o valor de `destination` é uma string vazia (`""`), mas existem muitos outros usos, e, na verdade, isso não tem nenhuma ligação direta com a API do Cache, ela pode ser usada nesse evento, assim como você pode implementar ela fora do service worker

Todos os caches feitos são guardados na variável global [`caches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/caches), ela é uma lista de "grupos de cache", por exemplo, posso organizar os caches da minha api de acordo com a versão (`my-api-v1`, `my-api-v1.1`, `my-api-v2`, etc). Ao "abrir" um desess grupos com `cache.open` lhe é retornado uma Promisse com uma instância de [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) que pode ser usada para guardar as respostas das requisições

Apesar de ser uma API experimental, sua compatibilidade é boa, e está disponível na maioria navegadores, pode ver a lista completa e atualizada na [tabela da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache#Browser_compatibility)

Existe Polyfill, recentemente implementei a API Cache em um PWA usando [esse](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/serviceworker-cache-polyfill), você pode importar em um service worker usando a função [`importScripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts)

Comment: Por que o negativo?

Comment: baita resposta! :)